# What is an import statement where filename contains "+"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, import, header-files

I have seen in some source code (by other developers) something like this:

```
#import "SomeClass+SomeOtherClass.h"
```

What is the `+` for? What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you want to add functionality to an existing class (exp: `NSString`). You can do that by creating a subclass or you can use a category. And it is common to name the file where the category is defined using the pattern : `MyClass+MyCategory.h`.

For example, we can add a method `reverseString` to the class `NSString` in a category:

```
// File NSString+reversable.h
- (NSString *)reverseString;

// File NSString+reversable.m
- (NSString *)reverseString
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Have a look at this [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) for more information about categories.

Then you can use that category in another class:

```
#import "NSString+reversable.h"
// ...

NSString *aString = @"Hello!";
NSString *reversedString = [aString reverseString];
```

Answer (score 4):

The "+" in header/source filenames is - **by convention** - used to describe `Category` implementations.

**Example :**

Let's say you want to add some functionality to an existing class (e.g.the `NSString` class). (`NSString+Utilities.h`)

```
// NSString+Utilities.h

@interface NSString (Utilities)
-(NSString *) doSthWithThisString;
@end
```

---

```
// NSString+Utilities.m

@implementation NSString (Utilities)

-(NSString *) doSthWithThisString
{
  NSMutableString *transformedStr = [self copy];

  // Do sth

  return transformedStr;
}

@end
```

---

**Using it :**

```
// in another file

#import "NSString+Utilities.h"

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSString* myString = @"This is a string";

    // you may use our new NSString method as much as any already-existing one
    NSString* newString = [myString doSthWithThisString];
}
```

---

**Reference :**

- [Mac OS Developer Library - Categories & Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)
- [Objective-C Categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) - [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories)

Comment: lol, we both used an `NSString` extension as an example. +1  for the complete declaration of the extension.

Comment: @sch Hahaha... Yep, indeed; it's a pretty typical (and easy to get) example, isn't it?